# Create list in Pandas DataFrame and each list will concatenate column values from prior rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a pandas data_frame as below. Is there anyway to do it? Thank you

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column 1':['A','B','C'], 
                   'Column 2':[['A'],['A','B'],['A','B','C']]})


  Column 1   Column 2
0        A        [A]
1        B     [A, B]
2        C  [A, B, C]
```

Comment: What is your starting point?   What is the input?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have only *Column 1* and want to generate *Column 2*.

Initially I thought about *expanding*, with application of
a function joining the argument (*Series*) but it turned out
that *expanding* requires a numerical argument.

But your task can be performed using "ordinary" *apply*, with a function
which performs such "cumulation" on its own.

Start from defining a function adding its argument to the "internal" list
(held as its attribute) and returning each time a copy of the list
gathered so far:

```
def addTbl(x):
    addTbl.tbl.extend(x)
    return addTbl.tbl.copy()
```

Then initiate its *tbl* attribute to *[]*, apply it to each element of
*Column 1* and save the result in *Column 2*:

```
addTbl.tbl = []
df['Column 2'] = df['Column 1'].apply(addTbl)
```

Comment: Thank you Valdi_Bo! That is exactly what I am looking for.